# Generating a table with ngFor - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am making a test table from a class created. Current class should generate a table of available data in my html file. But I do not see anything generated.

I am using Angular 5.

```
Expected table:
type1   Car
type2   Plane
type3   Truck
```

Component File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { mService } from '../Dash/Dash.service';
import { m } from '../Dash/Dash.model;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-m',
  templateUrl: './m.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./m.component.css'],
  providers: [mService]
})
export class mComponent implements OnInit {

  mServ: m[]

  constructor(private _mService: mService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.mServ= this._mService.GetData(true);
  }

}
```

Service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { m } from '.Dash.model;

@Injectable()
export class mService {
  //sourc - not currently in use
  GetData(sour: boolean): m{

    var viewModel = new m();
    view.wheels= [
      "Car", "Plane", "Truck"
    ];

    view.type= [
      "type1", "type2", "type3"
    ];

    return view;
    }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Model file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class m{

  public wheels: Array<string>;
  public type: Array<string>;

  constructor() { }
}
```

HTML

```
   <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let mServ&& mServ.length'>
          <td>{{ mServ.wheels}}</td>
          <td>{{ mServ.type}}</td>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

ngFor syntax above is wrong, it should iterate among objects not length

```
<tr *ngFor='let mServObj of mServ'>
```

if you want to check for *ngIf, you could do as,

```
 <tbody>
       <ng-container *ngIf= "mServ&& mServ.length > 0">
         <tr *ngFor='let mServObj of mServ'>
          <td>{{ mServ.wheels}}</td>
          <td>{{ mServ.type}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Guess, he wanted to have it as `*ngif` :-)

Comment: @DavidR Updated as above

Comment: Yes I meant to have it as ngIf, with ngFor to generate the table with each available data.

I just made the edit and I still don't see anything created on my page.

Comment: I have an error here:


      mServ: m[  ]

      ngOnInit() {
         this.mServ= this._mService.GetData(true);
      }

It says "Type m is not assignable to type m[ ]
Property 'include' is missing  in type m"

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
in your component.  I have removed the service call, but assigning it to a value amounts to the same effect.
    //service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public getData(source: boolean): Array<any> {
    return [{
      'wheels' : ['plane', 'truck', 'car'],
      'types': ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']
    }];
  }
}
```

App Component

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public view: any;
  constructor(private svc: MyService) {
    this.view =  this.svc.getData(true);

  }
}
```

Html Template

```
<table>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let s of  view'>
          <!-- <td>
            {{s | json}}
          </td> -->
          <span *ngFor='let it of s.wheels; index as i' [attr.data-index]="i">
            <td>{{s.wheels[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{s.types[i]}}</td>
          </span>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Updated to use a service.

Comment: That works, now I need to use the custom class that I made. Like my original attempt.

Comment: I think you should be able to instantiate and create the class - have you attempted it at all?

Comment: Hello, my table is displayed with commas...how do I remove them ? in my webpage the table shows as : test1, test2, test3 but I don't want to display the commas there...

Comment: I dont see that in my template.  May be you have an extra comma somewhere?