# How to post the dynamic form data?

Tags: angular6

I have a drop-down menu and a form with dynamic textbox.

This is my dropdown menu, which on change I store them to firstYear and secondYear

```
<select class="form-control" id="year" name="year" [(ngModel)]="yearRange" (change)="onFilter($event)">
    <option value='2018-2019'>2018-2019</option>
    <option value='2017-2018'>2017-2018</option>
    <option value='2016-2017'>2016-2017</option>
</select>


public updateForm: NgForm;
    public value_01: any; public value_02: any; public value_03: any;

onFilter(data: any) {
  ....
  yearSplit =  this.yearRange.split("-");
  this.firstYear = yearSplit[0];
  this.secondYear = yearSplit[1];
}
```

I want to post the form with key as countryname_year_1 for lets say country selected is "India", year is "2018" and month is january. I have tried following code. I am working here:

[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcnxrq](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcnxrq)

```
<form name="updateForm" #updateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(updateForm.value)" *ngIf="showEdit" >
    <div class="forex">
        <table class="table table-bordered">     
            <tr>
                <td>{{firstYear}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_01" name="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_01" [(ngModel)]="value_01"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_02" name="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_02" [(ngModel)]="value_02"></td>
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Can anybody please help me?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

your using same property for different rows, instead of that change property to Object then use it in template.

> do some changes in your template like

```
selectedYears: Object = {};

onFilter(data: any) {
  ....
  yearSplit =  this.yearRange.split("-");
  this.selectedYears[yearSplit[0]]= yearSplit[1];

  //  this way you don't need to set these to properties
  //  this.firstYear = yearSplit[0];
  //  this.secondYear = yearSplit[1];
}

genarateObjectKeys(years: any) {
  return Object.keys(years);
}
```

> in template

```
<tr *ngFor="let firstyear of genarateObjectKeys(selectedYears)">
    <td>{{firstYear}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_01" name="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_01" [(ngModel)]="value_01"></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_02" name="{{labelCountry}}_{{firstYear}}_02" [(ngModel)]="value_02"></td>
</tr>
```

you can get the secondyear in the template as `selectedYears[firstyear]`.
For more details about using *ngFor in the table [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287422/generating-a-table-with-ngfor-angular-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395529/angular-6-ngfor-list-of-tables-grouped-by-key/50396169)

Comment: inside genarateObjectKeys() i get {2016: "2017", 2017: "2018", 2018: "2019"} multiple times for the year selected 2018-2019

Comment: years =  {2016: "2017", 2017: "2018", 2018: "2019"}; this what you need to get inside `genarateObjectKeys()`. and it will return [2016,2017,2018] to template

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcnxrq can you please check here. i have 2 dropdown select country and year range then value must pass as country_firstYear_01 for if 2018 year is selected and text field january

Comment: Yes as key then it's associated value

Comment: see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb2qcf?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts it's not done yet but i think it will be useful to you